# Cocos2d thinks Im programming for Mac; but I'm not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm just starting with cocos2d, and I'm trying to set isTouchEnabled in the init method of my layer. But it only comes up with the Mac version in the auto type box (isMouseEnabled, and isKeyboardEnabled, rather than touch and accelerometer)

All I have is started a new project from the cocos2d template (with no addons like box2d), and changed nothing.

I have tried manually typing the `isTouchEnabled` but it won't build; saying that the setter doesn't exist.

For some reason it thinks I'm programming for Mac, although I also put this code(which is what cocos2d uses to differentiate)  in the init method of the layer and `iphone` was written to the console:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    NSLog(@"iphone");
#elif __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
NSLog(@"mac");  
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because they added Mac support, and for some reason it doesn't see the iphone, only the mac version. It works properly if you switch to Device, from simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I recall when I installed the cocos2d framework, I had to choose between the mac & iOS versions.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_1._install_test

```
cd cocos2d-iphone
./install-templates.sh
```

Comment: I ran that in terminal, but I never saw anywhere to choose between Mac and iOS, I don't even want anything to do with mac in my project, especially when the download was named cocos2d- **iphone**.